# Convert IGrouping to IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model called CelebrityLocation which has, amongst other properties, a Celebrity model.

So;

```
public partial class CelebrityLocation
  public Celebrity Celebrity {get; set;}
```

I want to get a list of all the `CelebrityLocation` objects but group that by `Celebrity` within the `CelebrityLocation`.

I get a return type of IGroupng but I need to convert that to an `IQueryable<CelebrityLocation>`.

The below is what I have been trying so far.

```
IQueryable<CelebrityLocation> returnSet = (IQueryable<CelebrityLocation>) dc.CelebrityLocations.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).GroupBy(x => x.Celebrity);
```

**Edit**

Is AutoMapper a viable solution in this case?

Comment: Why do you want an `IQueryable`? It's already in memory.

Comment: @SLaks because this is an existing method I am changing and there are many dependancies on this remaining IQueryable

Comment: You should probably change them all to `IEnumerable`, unless it will sometimes operate on an actual queryable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
dc.CelebrityLocations.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).AsQueryable().GroupBy(x => x.Celebrity).Select(x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you want to just get flat `IQueryable<CelebrityLocation>` just that grouped elements are next to each other?

If so, this should help:

```
IQueryable<CelebrityLocation> returnSet = dc.CelebrityLocations.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).GroupBy(x => x.Celebrity).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: +1 as this is almost there but the answer from Fulvio got me there.  Thanks anyway

Comment: @griegs so you just needed only first element of each group?

Comment: @griegs ok, I didn't get it from your original post.

Answer (score -2):

You can just call `AsQueryable()`.

Comment: I get this when I try to do that; Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[DataRepository.Celebrity,DataRepository.CelebrityLocation]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DataRepository.CelebrityLocation]